# how run fitnesse-standalone.jar as 32 bit on 64 bit mashine

Tags: java, fitnesse

I want to test my 32 bit assemblies with fitnesse on my 64 bit windows7.

I run fitnesse on a 64 bit windows 7 with the command:

`java -jar C:\Projects\fitnesse\fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 8888`

and it works nicely for assemblies that are compiled to 64 bit.

My assemblies are build with x86 flag i.e. - to 32 bit.

Hence I need to run fitnesse as a 32 bit process how do I do that?

I've tried with CorFlags.exe and the /32bit+ flag set, but I cannot get it to work.

how can I do that with the `java -jar *fitnesse-standalone.jar - p 8888` ?

or do i have to write the TEST_RUNNER or COMMAND_PATTERN tht uses the CorFlags.exe with the /32BIT+ flag?

---

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r "fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer,C:\fitnesse\fitsharp\fit.dll" %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {c:\fitnesse\fitsharp\Runner.exe}
```

---

Comment: How is this related to C# or .NET?

Comment: Did you run corflags /32bit+ against Runner.exe?  That should solve the problem.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks Andy for this, you saved med hours of investigation. So the solution was simply to run CorFlags,exe TestRunner.Exe /32BIT+ and the calls from Fitnesse works nicely. Something similar should be done with the testrunner used with slim is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

> Hence I need to run fitnesse as a 32 bit process how do I do that?

Install and use a 32-bit Java runtime environment (JRE).

Note that Java bytecode is architecture-agnostic; you don't compile Java code for a 32-bit or 64-bit architecture. Whether your Java program runs as a 32-bit or 64-bit process, depends on the version of the Java runtime environment that you use.

Comment: I tried this, and it turned out not to be the problem. I should run CorFlags TestRunner.exe /32BIT+ as suggested by Andy in a different answser/Comment.

Answer (score 0):

Simple option is to pull the source for fitsharp and compile as 32 bit executable.

Second option is to use coreflags utility from windows SDK and set the runner parameter to "coreflags runner.exe /32bit" i dont remember the parameters for coreflags to just check and use correct one.